# Python fwrite function error: a bytes like object is required, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is several errors "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'. But none of them is related to mine. I open the file using open(filename, "w"), not "wb". The code is like 150 lines long. The beginning of the code is to assign the input of command line into parser args.

The args.result is an empty txt file which I want to write my result onto. 
I open it using open.

I think the following code should be enough to illustrate my question. Before the line 65, the code is writing two functions to be used in calculation but I think it should be irrelevant to the bug.

In the code, I manually create the file 'save/results/result.txt' in the command terminal. Then I open the file in the line 132.
[image]
[image]
The remaining code is 
[image]
[image]
A interesting bug happens that the line 158 runs OK. "begin training\n" can be written into file. Then for the line 165, during the first time of loop, it is OK and "aa\n" can be written into file. But during the second loop, the program end with an error "a bytes-like" object is required, not 'str'. The error message is as following.
[image]

Anyone could provide a help of that?
Quite thanks.

Comment: `f.write(b"aa\n")`?

Comment: I tried, but not work...

Comment: Could you post the code as text? And did you redefine f to be anything else?

Comment: Please also add the line where you open the file, and the exception handler

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The provided code is incomplete and cannot be used to reproduce the issue. How should anyone be able to provide help? Please fix.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to just upload part of the code. I am revising my question now!\

Answer (score -1):

I've never had trouble with similar code, but if you want a quick fix, I'd bet making a string named f_text and adding to it within the for loop, then writing all of it to the file after the last iteration of the for loop would be a simple way to circumvent the problem.

IE:

```
f_text = ""
for epoch in range(your_range):
    # Do calculations
    print(the_stuff_you_wanted_to)
    f_text += the_stuff_you_wanted_to + "\n"
f.write(f_text)
```

I'm mostly posting this to act as a quick fix though. I feel that there's probably a better solution and could help more if you show more of your code, like where you actually initialize f.

Comment: The error says that a byte object is required, not a string. How would making everything a string help?

Comment: You said that your command on line 158 worked, and that uses a string. If you opened the file with 'w', then write should take a string. Since every time you've tried to write a string to f outside the for loop, it stands to reason that trying to write a string to it after the for loop terminates could work.

Comment: In python you can easily break stuff from higher level scopes. Since the loop is possibly breaking the file stream it is expected that after the loop is completed it is still broken. I also tend to prefer letting the OP work for his question to be good before throwing an answer. At this point his question is as broken as `f`.

Comment: That makes sense, but then if the objective is to print a report to the file, would closing it before the for loop and opening it again after before writing work?